# GNU gettext ignores set locale

Tags: c++, windows, gettext

I'm trying to use GNU gettext in a C++ program running on MS Windows. I manage to set the locale as for instance
`char *locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "French_France.1252");`

I check the returned string so I know it took.

Then I set the environment as

```
textdomain("Test");
bindtextdomain("Test", "C:\\develop\\test\\executablesdebug\\Language\\");
```

Then I do an experimental translation, like

`char *test = gettext("Hello world");`

And the translated string gets the Swedish translation (the operating system setting) and not the French string I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can remember in Windows you also have to set the thread locale using [`SetThreadLocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-setthreadlocale) (you will have to map to the locale ID, take a look at [this webpage](https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php)).

Finally, take into consideration that in Windows each thread has its own locale; set it for all threads using translations.

Comment: Nope, fr_FR does not work (setLocale returns an empty string). The structure works as I get messages translated to Swedish using it.

Comment: Please try then the thread-related part of the answer, I remember having issues between English and Spanish with that